# Identify Calling Application in Android NDK

Tags: android, authentication, android-ndk

I have a native android library (.so) I am bundling with some application. In the native code I want to verify the signer/package name of the calling application.

The reason is, currently anyone can open up the .apk file take my .so file and use it to built their own applications.

Is there a way to securely identify the calling application from Java side? This could be package name, signature or anything else that can identify the Android application in a unique way.

Answer (score 2):

JNI code is coupled with Java package name, and can be called only from the same package and class. To improve security further, you can check some Java `private static final` field from the JNI code.

Comment: Another application can just use the same package and class name to call the functions. That is not difficult, they just need to look at the list of exported functions from the .so file.

But I guess, private static final field could add additional security. An attacker still can get around this by disassembling my application but that is a long shot.

Thank you for the answer!

Comment: An attacker could always bring your defenses down. The best security is the legal defense

Comment: You could arrange some fancy cryptographic call & response protocol with the app, but any check you add to the .so can be disabled by modifying the .so.  You can make reuse of your code arbitrarily difficult but you can't make it impossible.  Decide how much effort you're willing to put into it.

Answer (score 0):

> In the native code I want to verify the signer/package name of the
> calling application.

how about this?

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <string>

extern "C"
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
Java_com_x_y_TestActivity_stringFromJNI(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz)
{ 
    jclass jActivity_class = env->GetObjectClass(thiz);
    jmethodID jMethod_id_pn = env->GetMethodID(jActivity_class,"getPackageName","()Ljava/lang/String;");
    jstring package_name = (jstring) env->CallObjectMethod(thiz,jMethod_id_pn);
    return package_name;
}
```